# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined - Node.js SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am trying to update the post title of a post with ID = 1 using mysql npm package and node.js. The following are the routes for creating a post and updating the post:

```
app.get("/addpost", (req,res)=>{
  let post = {title: "Post one", body: "Body of post 1"};
  let sql = 'INSERT INTO posts SET ?' 
  db.query(sql, post, (err,result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send('POST 1 has been created in DB');
  });
});

app.get("/updatepost", (req,res)=>{
  let sql = "UPDATE posts SET title = 'Hi' WHERE id = 1";
  console.log(sql);
  db.query(sql, (err,result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(result[0].title);
    });
});
```

The following is the error received when I go to /updatepost:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

I have no idea why I am encountering this error. When I check the database on MySQL Workbench, I see that the value is updated, however, the route fails.

Comment: `UPDATE` queries don't have a result set.

Comment: Use `console.log(result);` to see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a `SELECT` query to get a result set. `UPDATE` queries just return status information, not data rows.

```
app.get("/updatepost", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "UPDATE posts SET title = 'Hi' WHERE id = 1";
  console.log(sql);
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.query("SELECT title FROM posts WHERE id = 1", (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send(result[0].title);
    });
  });
});
```